# Какая функция в nodejs может определить папку в замен устаревшей isDirectory()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

На попытку определить является ли переданный путь папкой  `if (await fs.stat(path).isDirectory()) { path += '/index.html'; }` нода выдаёт ошибку: TypeError: fs.stat(...).isDirectory is not a function

Comment: Может прочитать документацию?

Comment: С чего это она устарела? https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#statsisdirectory

Comment: как ты импортируешь `fs`? Какую именно версию `.stat` вызываешь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `isDirectory` не является устаревшей.

В данном случае происходит некорректное использование метода `stat`.

Если предположить, что используется версия [fsPromises](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fspromisesstatpath-options).

Данный метод возвращает `Promise`, который надо дождаться с помощью `await`. В данном случае

```
await fs.stat(path).isDirectory()
```

`await` применяется ко всему выражению `fs.stat(path).isDirectory()`, следовательно `isDirectory` вызывается у `Promise`. Такой метод отсутствует, поэтому и происходит ошибка.

Для исправления достаточно расставить скобки:

```
(await fs.stat(path)).isDirectory()
```